# AttributeError at /app/api/get

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I got an error,
AttributeError at /app/api/get
Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `task_name` on serializer `TaskSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Color` instance.
Original exception text was: 'Color' object has no attribute 'task_name'.

Now I wanna make a page that shows model's content in json format.
models.py is

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Color(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    background_color = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    h1_color = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    p_color = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

serializers.py is

```
from .models import Color
from rest_framework import serializers

class TaskSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    task_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=100)
    status = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_task_status')

    def get_task_status(self, instance):
        return instance.status.status

    class Meta:
        model = Color
        fields = ('name',
                  'background_color',
                  'h1_color',
                  'p_color',
                  'task_name')
```

urls.py is

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'api/get',views.TaskGet.as_view(),name='task-get')
]
```

views.py is

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Color
from .forms import ColorForm
from .serializers import TaskSerializer
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response

from rest_framework import status

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    d = {
        'colors': Color.objects.all(),
        'form': ColorForm(),
    }
    return render(request, 'index.html', d)

class TaskGet(APIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        obj = Color.objects.all()
        serializers = TaskSerializer(obj, many=True)
        return Response(serializers.data, status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

I wrote `url(r'api/get',views.TaskGet.as_view(),name='task-get')` in urls.py,so I really cannot understand why this error happens.I already run commands of migration of model. How can I fix this?
My ideal web page is like
[image: ideal page]

Comment: include the full error traceback in the question

Comment: Your model and serializer are inconsistent. Why do you call the serializer `TaskSerializer` when the model is called `Color`? It looks unintentional.

Answer (score 1):

You try get `status` by foreign key `instance.status.status` but in your model `class Color` i don't see any foreign keys or methods for it.

And for `task_name` did you want to see the model field `name` try to add  [source params](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source)

```
task_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=100, source='name')
#                                                   ^^^^^^^^^
```

are you sure you want serialize `Task` for model `Color`?

**new edit**

in your `get_task_status` the 'instance`is instance of serializer model, so if your model`Color`has no property or method`status` you will catch an error

Comment: I added source='name' to my codes(so my code is task_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=100,source='name')),but now AttributeError at /app/api/get
'Color' object has no attribute 'status' error happens.Is this meaning several errors in my codes and one error solved?How shoould I do for next?

Comment: Why do I need ForeinKey in my model?I did not 2 or more models in my code.My model is only one.

Comment: what information do you want to get by `instance.status.status` from where?

Comment: I imitated a code on a web site,and get_task_status method is  in that code and its method returned instance.status.status.So i think get_task_status method is necessary but am I wrong it?

Comment: i edit the answer, i think you need read ore about python and django.